# Google Appengine Deployment with SSH keys

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, ssh

I'm trying to find a way to use SSH Keys instead of OAuth authentication for Google AppEngine Deployment, but as of now couldn't find a way yet.

Just to explain a bit more, I use `appcfg.py update PROJECT` to deploy on Appengine with OAuth that was set on the first run. However I want to switch it to use SSH keys, preferably Hardware SSH keys e.g Yubikeys.

Comment: Interesting use case, why do you need to do so? You can use the yubikey to secure the machine you're using to deploy.

Comment: Let's say to have a more secure deployment process from personal laptops.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is not involved in deploying to App Engine, so SSH keys will be of no use.

Comment: I know SSH is not involved, but as there's an authentication method involved, it can be a process to replace OAuth authentication